# parsing a local xml file without using tableview controller

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

Dear all,
I need parse a local xml file without using a navigation controller. And i studied all the documents. But still am confused.Can anyone explain me fully with one full sample example code.

or tell me how can i access/read the local xml file to display it in a uiwebview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing any kind of data and displaying it properly is a great way to boost your programming skills.

On the iPhone there are many options for parsing, but first you have to load your file:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                 pathForResource:@"MyFile" ofType:@"txt"];  
NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];  
if (myData) {  
    // do something useful  
}
```

Once you have that working, you can get to parsing the file. I love using [Xpath](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp), it makes finding the elements you need and  storing/displaying/manipulating becomes dead easy. There are some great libraries and frameworks for using Xpath.

My personal favorite is [XpathQuery](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html).

By the sound of things, you're going to be reading a simple file and displaying things in a pretty normal fashion. The following will work:

```
#import "XpathQuery"

NSArray *queryResult =  PerformXMLXPathQuery(myData, @"/aNode");

myTextField.text = [[queryResult objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];
```